# MySQL vs NoSQL , which one to use for calculating averages over a very large dataset

Tags: mysql, nosql

The problem is that I need to store 1 integer every day (adding new data with time stamp) for lots of entities every day (lets say 10s of million entities, but they could easily be 100 of million or even half a billion as the entities are growing in population)

The entities are grouped in an hierarchy and I can filter using those.

Now I would like a quick way to calculate average of these millions of values over a time period (and perhaps also only calculate average using filtered data). My gut instinct is that as this data grows (potentially 20 millions row every day it will be very hard to guarantee performance.

Can you suggest an easy solution. Should I stick with MySQL or some other fancy NoSQL solution would be better. As it stands it is already painfully slow to just count all the entities (perhaps MySQL needs tuning)

**Edit:**
So when values are retrieved, some values come as null (which mean that nothing can be said about those values). So in a query which spans between Jan 1, 2000 and Jan 10, 2000. If 2 values are null, then for average calculation, 8 data points would be used (and it would be divided by 8 for average calculation, so its not like dividing it by number of days). My concern is that even count(*) takes s*** load of time. Perhaps its about tuning, but I would be interested in some thing which doesn't need tuning and works for this particular problem as well

Comment: Benchmark, benchmark, benchamark and yes - MySQL probably needs tuning

Comment: changed the title for the voter who voted it down without reading the content.

Comment: you does not require mysql, but you need a super-computer like the one that laboratory using

Comment: @ajreal your comment escapes me, attempt at humor/sarcasm? Not every one runs a cluster, and the MySQL instance in question is on shall we say high performance server hardware/disarray.

Comment: @geoaxis -- there is always a hardware limit, 20 millions of record per day, how much disk space it will costs after 100 days? Is naturally the normal PC/servers does not designed for these purposes, that's why people invent larger size of computer at the first place (because it fit their needs)

Comment: @geoaxis -- otherwise, you should consider to store the calculated results (summarized data), that's mean for each of the entities, you should stored `day, entities, sum(entities value), count(entities excluding null)` only

Comment: +1 Why is this being downvoted? It's a good question.

Comment: @NullUserException -- check yourself -- http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/7176772/1

Comment: @geoaxis *maybe you got me wrong*, is good to see you mention your server grade. If you current setup is not fulfill your requirement, should not you having doubts on the hardware limit?

Comment: well my question has a basis on claims by Neo4j that the same query which takes mere 2 milliseconds on a graphdb takes an hour on relational database. I am not an operations guy but I know if hardware is the issue. I guess what I hoped to find was some other approach to the problem, OLAP seems to be the direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably look into OLAP solutions, where aggregated data is the name of the game. RDBMSs typically don't handle aggregation that well (of course, there are ways to assist it with indexing, partitioning, etc.). But, OLAP cubes are designed to handle large amounts of aggregation and slicing/dicing on the fly.

Comment: interesting, didn't consider that as an option, will look into it.

Answer (score 1):

i think either one would do.  The trick to calculate a running average is to do it as you insert, not on demand.  Averages are easy because its just the sum divided by the number of addends.

You can use database triggers to do it as things get inserted (or updated, or deleted), and with nosql I *think* the views get updated automagically for you.  With a sql solution, you can also do it in your application as part of your service layer.

Comment: see my addition, I don't see how I can (easily) calculate an average for every conceivable view. The average has to be calculated upon view since it has filtering by group, sub group, sub sub group, date range etc

Comment: @geoaxis, i dont see the problem.  As you insert the data, do the calculation, so when you need the result you have it somewhere.  Even if you have to do a lot of logic and keep multiple averages, its still better than calculating on demand, as a calculation on hundreds of millions of rows is going to be expensive.